# Difference between host based authentication and key based authentication

Tags: linux, authentication

I did a bit of research on google but was not able to get satisfactory answer. Can anyone please clarify same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Host based authentication is where the host (or server) is authenticated so some users can just authenticate without the need of a key or whatsoever.

Key base authentication is where you, as a user generate a public and private key from your machine or host. You share your generated public key and then you can authenticate anywhere where a host has your public key (usually to avoid typing passwords).

More info:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Host-based_Authentication

I hope it helps

Comment: What is the most secure ?

Comment: For me it would be the key based authentication because the host based authentication wouldn't control WHO uses the host. If you want to use a combination of both it would be the best option of course.